# Printf prints an additional % on Mac OS

Tags: c, printf

Consider the following simple program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand(1);
    int l;
    double r;
    l = atoi(argv[1]);
    r = (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX * l;
    printf("%f", r);
}
```

Executing with `./helper.x 3` I get the strange output `0.000023%` (there's a `%` unwanted character at the end of the number). Initially I thought it was due to `atoi` function, but even with a fixed value for `l` the result is the same. I am on Mac OS (don't know if this can explain somehow this behaviour). I noticed that putting `\n` at the end of the format specifier the `%` character disappears, so how can this be explained?

## EDIT:

I don't really know what my shell prompt is (nor what a shell prompt is actually). Here is a screenshot of the output, the first run is without the end string character `\n`, while the second has the `\n`. (there is also a run without `argv` which of course ended in segmentation fault).
[image]

Comment: My guess? That the extra `%` is your shell *prompt*. Try printing a trailing newline, as in `printf("%f\n", r);`, do the `%` come on the next line instead?

Comment: Or change your shell prompt and you will see another character at the end ;-)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no with `\n` at the end it does not display. So is it normal? Is it possible to get rid of it?

Comment: Just to be clear about a couple of things: First off, what is your shell prompt? Secondly, have you copy-pasted the exact source you're building into the question? And can you possible [edit] your question to include a screenshot of your terminal window where you run both programs (both without and with the newline)?

Comment: The extra `%` is something that "cool" shells add (along with a `\n`) when they see there is no new line, to indicate that the new line is missing, and also to avoid putting the prompt on the same line, which is hideous. Both ZSH and Fish shell do this for example.

Comment: If you're using `zsh`, you can run `echo -n XXXXXX` and watch the `%` appear.

Answer (score 4):

the code you show doesnt print a % on macos (I tried it using CodeRunner)
It might be an artifact from the terminal (e.g. maybe your command prompt)

Try printing a newline in the end of your output so the shell correctly starts on the next line

`printf("%f", r);` => `printf("%f\n", r);`

Comment: The advice to end outputs with a newline is correct.  Technically, the code in the program doesn't print the extra `%` and newline; the shell that invokes the program does that — if the shell is `zsh` or `fish` (or …).